# How to set css styles on storybook iframes

Tags: storybook

I wish to set some styling on the storybook canvas and docs at a global level. Could anyone suggest me a way out?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-rendering#adding-to-body to customize the iframe or https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/theming#global-theming to globally define a theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preview-header.html` for that. Just add that file to your `.storybook` folder. Then add a style tag there, e.g.:

```html
<style>
   body {
     font-size: 15px;
   }
</style>
```

All it's contents are being injected to the Storybook preview Iframe, so you can add styles as well as other scripts and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/theming#global-theming

Create `manager-head.html` file in `.storybook` directory and set your styles in

```
<style>
...
</style>
```